# Calculate Summation of series

Tags: calculus

One of my homework:

Compute $\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}\alpha_i - (k-1) $  given $\alpha_i$ is $\frac{k-1}{k}$

Answer given is zero.

So i suspect that $\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}\frac{k-1}{k}=k-1$?

But how can i get the answer?

Comment: First of all, what is $k$? $$k\in\mathbb N?$$
That is the only logical assumption in this case, although:
$$k\in\mathbb Q,k>1$$
could work under some circumstances.

As given in the task $\alpha_i$ is an (independent) $\text{constant}$, otherwise, it wouldn't work, so you can write just $\alpha$ without an index instead.

Answer (score 0):

Note that

$$\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}\alpha_i = \frac{k-1}{k}\cdot\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}1=\frac{k-1}{k}\cdot k = k-1 $$.

Comment: what mean by trivial?

Comment: @measure2012 very simple, but I will delete it.

Comment: ok, i understand already...Thanks @mathse